# Azure Devops Run Result Steps and Run Summary Details Attachments API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management

I am trying to fetch the attachments of the Test Run Result steps and Test Run Result Summary Details but unable to find any API related to that
I am attaching the Image below Rectangle 1 is the attchments for Test Run Result Steps and Rectangele 2 is the attachments for Test Run Result Summary Detais
[image]

If anyone have any knowledge about these perticular apis please let me know.

I have checked the [AZURE API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-sub-result-attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but couldn't find the specific API if I have missied something please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling the [Get Test Result Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-result-attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API, we can get all the IDs of the attachments:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

After that, if you want to get the attachments you can call [Attachments - Get Test Result Attachment Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-result-attachment-zip?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API with the specific `Attachment ID`.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments/{attachmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Please note that the REST API [Attachments - Get Test Result Attachment Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-result-attachment-zip?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)  will display the context of the attachments instead of download the attachments directly. If you want to download the attachments, you can write a script to save them to a local directory. The following PowerShell script for your reference:

```
$AttachmentsOutfile = "D:\Test\HellWorld.java"

$connectionToken="You PAT Here"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::  
ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$AuditLogURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments/{attachmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1" 

$AuditInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AuditLogURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get –OutFile $AttachmentsOutfile
```

**UPDATE:**

However the [Get Test Result Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-result-attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API can only get the attachments attached from the test run UI (attached by clicking the `Add attachment` button).

To get the attachments of the Test Run Result steps and Test Run Result Summary, we can call [Results - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API with parameter `detailsToInclude=iterations` added:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=iterations&api-version=6.0
```

[image]

[image]

After that we can download the attachments by their ID. The following PowerShell script for your reference to download them in a loop:

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}",
   [string]$project = "Test0924",
   [string]$downloadlocation = "C:\temp\1025\",
   [string]$TestRunId = "1000294",
   [string]$ResultId = "100000",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#List test result and test step attachments: 
$testresultUrl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/test/Runs/$TestRunId/Results/$($ResultId)?detailsToInclude=iterations&api-version=6.0" 
$attachments = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $testresultUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).iterationDetails.attachments

ForEach ($attachment in $attachments) {
#Get test result and step attachments:
$attachmentid = $attachment.id
$attachmentname = $attachment.name
$attachmenturl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/test/Runs/$TestRunId/Results/$ResultId/attachments/$($attachmentid)?api-version=6.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $attachmenturl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile $downloadlocation\$attachmentname
}
```

Comment: GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=6.0-preview.1

This api is not fetching any of the attachments I have mentioned 
It only fetches the Run Result Attachmnets 
I am trying to get the attachments that are in the Run Step Section

Comment: It's the test case step attachments, generally we can get it from the test case.

Comment: Have you checked the new updated ADO instance it is valid for the old instances @Andy Li-MSFT

Comment: @swx See the updated answer, we can call [Results - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API with parameter `detailsToInclude=iterations` added to get the test steps and test result attachments:  `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=iterations&api-version=6.0`